# can we combine lasso or elastic net regressor with kernel?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using sklearn for training and testing my data. I want to use lasso and elastic net regressors with some kernel instead of using Linear model. Is there a possible way in which this can be done?

Comment: Lasso and Elastic Net are available in `sklearn` only for linear models. If you want to use a specific kernel you can use `KernelRidge` that combines Ridge regression with the kernel trick

Comment: I need to combine error minimization technique of Linear models with support vector regression which actually minimizes errors using epsilon-sensitive technique.

Comment: fair enough. Is there any question ?

Comment: I want to know whether I can do what I am intending to do i.e. combine error minimization technique of Linear models with SVR. If yes, then how can I do so?